# Servlet.service I/O error on GET request for microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I'm trying to test something out with microservices.

I have 3 service:

- UserService (Bean)
- DepartmentService (Bean)
- ServiceRegistry (EurekaServer)

when i Like to get a Departmen fitting to my User because my RestTemplate in the UserService can't connect to the Department.

**UserService of User**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public User saveUser(User user) {
        log.info("Inside saveUser of UserService");
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public ResponseTemplateVO getUserWithDepartment(Long userId) {
        log.info("Inside getUserWithDepartment of UserService");
        ResponseTemplateVO vo = new ResponseTemplateVO();
        User user = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);

        Department department =
                restTemplate.getForObject("http://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE/departments/" + user.getDepartmentId()
                        ,Department.class);

        vo.setUser(user);
        vo.setDepartment(department);

        return  vo;
    }
}
```

**application.yml UserService**

```
server:
  port: 9092

spring:
  application:
    name: USER-SERVICE

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
      instance:
        hostname: localhost
```

**UserService UserServiceApplication**

```
package com.dailycodebuffer.user;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class UserServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

**UserService ServiceRegistry application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

ErrorCode

```
2021-06-12 22:35:41.186 ERROR 40280 --- [nio-9092-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE/departments/2": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect] with root cause
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you encounter any problems because you are using the original `IP` address of `Department Service`?

Comment: So in Postman my get URL looks like this: http://localhost:9092/users/1 

If you meant the code when I like to get the department i also tried it like this: 
   Department department =
                restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9002/departments/" + user.getDepartmentId()
                        ,Department.class);

But it doesn't work also ... I can share you my Project if that helps

Comment: As far as I understand, your `department-service` application is not working. Are you sure the correct application is running?

Comment: Yes ... so as I think the department service is working, because I'm able to post things in it. But when I like to get a User, Department pair in the getUserWithDepartment method my Resttemplate can't  connect to the Department I think.

Comment: https://github.com/rafu07/Microservices here is my project if that helps